# SQL dúvida com COUNT

Tags: sql

Olá, tenho uma query conforme abaixo, e tenho algumas dúvidas referente ao `COUNT`, gostaria de ajuda para entender e resolver o problema :

```
public String getQueryPrincipal(String queryPrincipal) {
        return queryPrincipal = " select YEAR(entrada_acidente.data_criacao) as ano,"
                //+ " COUNT(entrada_acidente.cliente_id ) AS ct," 
                + " cliente.id AS cliente_id," 
                + " cliente.doc_receita_federal AS cliente_doc_receita_federal,"
                + " cliente.email AS cliente_email," 
                + " cliente.nome AS cliente_nome,"
                + " cliente.tipo AS cliente_tipo," 
                + " condutor.id AS condutor_id,"
                + " condutor.codigo AS condutor_codigo," 
                + " condutor.nome AS condutor_nome,"
                + " despesa.id AS despesa_id," 
                + " despesa.nome AS despesa_nome," 
                + " despesa.sku AS despesa_sku,"
                + " despesa.categoria_id AS despesa_categoria_id," 
                + " entrada_acidente.id AS entrada_acidente_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.attach AS entrada_acidente_attach,"
                + " entrada_acidente.data_criacao AS entrada_acidente_data_criacao,"
                + " entrada_acidente.fileName AS entrada_acidente_fileName,"
                + " entrada_acidente.forma_pagamento AS entrada_acidente_forma_pagamento,"
                + " entrada_acidente.observacao AS entrada_acidente_observacao,"
                + " entrada_acidente.status AS entrada_acidente_status,"
                + " entrada_acidente.valor_total AS entrada_acidente_valor_total,"
                + " entrada_acidente.cliente_id AS entrada_acidente_cliente_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id AS entrada_acidente_ocorrencia_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.vendedor_id AS entrada_acidente_vendedor_id,"
                + " entrada_acidente.valor_unitario AS entrada_acidente_valor_unitario,"
                + " item_despesa.id AS item_despesa_id," + " item_despesa.despesa_id AS item_despesa_despesa_id,"
                + " item_despesa.entrada_id AS item_despesa_entrada_id," + " ocorrencia.id AS ocorrencia_id,"
                + " ocorrencia.descricao AS ocorrencia_descricao,"
                + " ocorrencia.condicao_tempo AS ocorrencia_condicao_tempo,"
                + " ocorrencia.data_ocorrencia AS ocorrencia_data_ocorrencia,"
                + " ocorrencia.numero_vitimas AS ocorrencia_numero_vitimas,"
                + " ocorrencia.periodo_ocorrencia AS ocorrencia_periodo_ocorrencia" 
                + " FROM " + " cliente cliente "
                + " INNER JOIN (select COUNT( * ) as countTotal " + "FROM entrada_acidente)AS t "
                //+ " INNER JOIN (select COUNT( entrada_acidente.id ) as ct " + "FROM entrada_acidente)AS tt "
                + " INNER JOIN (select SUM( entrada_acidente.valor_unitario ) as soma " + "FROM entrada_acidente)AS ttt "
                + " INNER JOIN entrada_acidente entrada_acidente ON cliente.id = entrada_acidente.cliente_id "

                + " INNER JOIN item_despesa item_despesa ON entrada_acidente.id = item_despesa.entrada_id"
                + " INNER JOIN ocorrencia ocorrencia ON entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id = ocorrencia.id"
                + " INNER JOIN condutor condutor ON ocorrencia.condutor_id = condutor.id"
                + " INNER JOIN despesa despesa ON item_despesa.despesa_id = despesa.id";
    }
```

Está funcionado corretamente, porém se eu remover o comentário desta linha:(1º dúvida)

```
//+ " COUNT(entrada_acidente.cliente_id ) AS ct,"
```

recebo apenas um registro como retorno. Tenho 12 registros no momento.

Esta linha : (2º dúvida)

```
COUNT(entrada_acidente.cliente_id ) AS ct
```

deveria me dar a quantidade de cada cliente(quantidade de registros de cada cliente) considerando as restriçoes feitas na query?

Esta linha: (3º dúvida)

```
+ " INNER JOIN (select COUNT( * ) as countTotal " + "FROM entrada_acidente)AS t "
```

deveria me dar a quantidade total de registros na tabela?

São estas três questões que gostaria de ajuda para resolver/entender.
Obrigado.

Comment: Amigo, seria interessante postar a SQL formatada. Ficou muito difícil retirar os caracteres de formatação para editar uma resposta...

Comment: Vou ajustar e postar novamente.

Comment: Já respondi, mas não consigo garantir que esteja 100% porque não tenho sua estrutura de banco de dados, nem foi postada a estrutura das tabelas, então tive que assumir alguns cenários.

Comment: Estou vendo sua resposta agora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sua query está bastante errada. Você não deve fazer JOIN em um count. Ao adicionar um count ele vai realizar uma agregação, e, fatalmente, retornar uma única linha. Acredito que a query que você esteja procurando seja a seguinte:

```
 SELECT Year(entrada_acidente.data_criacao) AS ano,
       -- total de acidentes no sistema
       (SELECT Count(1) 
        FROM   entrada_acidente) AS countTotal,
       -- total de acidentes desse cliente, nessa ocorrencia
       -- dependendo do seu banco precisa apenas filtrar por occorrencia.id (ou item_despeda.entrada_id)
       (SELECT Count(1) 
        FROM   entrada_acidente
        WHERE  entrada_acidente.cliente_id = cliente.id
               AND entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id = ocorrencia.id
               AND entrada_acidente.id = item_despesa.entrada_id) AS ct,
       -- soma dos valores dos acidentes desse cliente, nessa ocorrencia
       -- dependendo do seu banco precisa apenas filtrar por occorrencia.id
       (SELECT Sum(valor_unitario) 
        FROM   entrada_acidente
        WHERE  entrada_acidente.cliente_id = cliente.id
               AND entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id = ocorrencia.id
               AND entrada_acidente.id = item_despesa.entrada_id) AS soma,

        cliente.id AS cliente_id, 
        cliente.doc_receita_federal AS cliente_doc_receita_federal,
        cliente.email AS cliente_email, 
        cliente.nome AS cliente_nome,
        cliente.tipo AS cliente_tipo,
        condutor.id AS condutor_id,
        condutor.codigo AS condutor_codigo,
        condutor.nome AS condutor_nome,
        despesa.id AS despesa_id,
        despesa.nome AS despesa_nome,
        despesa.sku AS despesa_sku,
        despesa.categoria_id AS despesa_categoria_id,
        entrada_acidente.id AS entrada_acidente_id,
        entrada_acidente.attach AS entrada_acidente_attach,
        entrada_acidente.data_criacao AS entrada_acidente_data_criacao,
        entrada_acidente.fileName AS entrada_acidente_fileName,
        entrada_acidente.forma_pagamento AS entrada_acidente_forma_pagamento,
        entrada_acidente.observacao AS entrada_acidente_observacao,
        entrada_acidente.status AS entrada_acidente_status,
        entrada_acidente.valor_total AS entrada_acidente_valor_total,
        entrada_acidente.cliente_id AS entrada_acidente_cliente_id,
        entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id AS entrada_acidente_ocorrencia_id,
        entrada_acidente.vendedor_id AS entrada_acidente_vendedor_id,
        entrada_acidente.valor_unitario AS entrada_acidente_valor_unitario,
        item_despesa.id AS item_despesa_id, item_despesa.despesa_id AS item_despesa_despesa_id,
        item_despesa.entrada_id AS item_despesa_entrada_id, ocorrencia.id AS ocorrencia_id,
        ocorrencia.descricao AS ocorrencia_descricao,
        ocorrencia.condicao_tempo AS ocorrencia_condicao_tempo,
        ocorrencia.data_ocorrencia AS ocorrencia_data_ocorrencia,
        ocorrencia.numero_vitimas AS ocorrencia_numero_vitimas,
        ocorrencia.periodo_ocorrencia AS ocorrencia_periodo_ocorrencia
        FROM  cliente 
        INNER JOIN entrada_acidente entrada_acidente ON cliente.id = entrada_acidente.cliente_id 
        INNER JOIN item_despesa item_despesa ON entrada_acidente.id = item_despesa.entrada_id
        INNER JOIN ocorrencia ocorrencia ON entrada_acidente.ocorrencia_id = ocorrencia.id
        INNER JOIN condutor condutor ON ocorrencia.condutor_id = condutor.id
        INNER JOIN despesa despesa ON item_despesa.despesa_id = despesa.id
```

Comment: Esta query eu uso em um relatório `JasperReports`, e está dando uma `exception` aqui: `TextColumnBuilder<Integer> Qtd = col.column("qtd ", "ct", type.integerType());` que é: `Unknown column name ct in result set.` E se eu alterar para as outras `aliases` que estão dentro de parenteses com select ocorre o mesmo.

Comment: Rodrigo, mudei ontem mesmo a query e coloquei os aliases fora. Não fazem sentido dentro do count. Se der esse erro é porque o alias não tá certo, já que tive que adivinhar um pouco o que você pretendia. Imagino que seja simples pra você agora ajustar os alias para atingir seus objetivos. Experimente rodar a query no banco direto pra ver se os resultados estão corretos.

Comment: @Rodrigo ainda está tendo problemas com os aliases?

Comment: Ainda não pude verificar.

Comment: Seguinte,deu certo, mas, precisei acrescentar uma verificação no count, pois estava retornando valores a maior,(por exemplo onde haviam 4 registros retornava 6), acrescentei o seguinte: `and entrada_acidente.id=item_despesa.entrada_id`. Está correto ou tenho problemas na estrutua das tabelas?

Comment: @Rodrigo perfeito! Eu mesmo fui adicionando as condições nos counts olhando para os seus joins, e acabei deixando passar essa. Me parece que suas tabelas estão corretas: você está contando o acidente no cliente, na ocorrência e no item de despesa retornado no registro em questão, ou seja, seu COUNT está sendo restringido pelas mesmas condições dos seus joins. Acho que está certo. Não tenho como opinar sobre seu banco (e isso não seria nem dentro do contexto da Stack Overflow!),mas me parece certinho!